# How to access websites serving ports different from 80?

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, port-forwarding, port

In my workplace we are allowed to browse regular 80 and 443 sites, however my school uses 8097 and other ports on several sites.

Sometimes I would like to advance some homework and connect to my school website. At the moment I have Guacamole running on a cheap aruba VPS, also tightvnc so I have a virtual desktop on my browser, It works but this approach is very laggy.

I wonder if there are a better way to use this VPS to redirect the traffic throught my server and serve to port 80 but connecting to the real port to my school website.

I'm trying to learn so if can give just the path and keywords or even the correct definition of this approach it could really help.

Comment: You can open an ssh server on port 80 on your vps and use port tunneling in order to connect to remote ports through your machine. I don't know exactly how this would work for you though..

Comment: That is a bit silly restriction, isn't it? What's the reasoning behind such a restriction? Is it possible for you to ask the network admin if he could add an exception for your school's website?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen By blocking unfamiliar ports, if a computer on the network becomes infected with malware, it cannot communicate to its' creator if it uses a port outside of 80 or 443.

Comment: @var firstName I'm hardly a security expert, but this doesn't seem like a good security measure. If it is, I guess the joke is on our IT department since we don't have such measures. Blessed be our open networks and malware infested workstations.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen It's not. I was just trying to play the devil's advocate and justify their blacklisting.

Comment: “How to bypass corporate IT” is off-topic here.  I’m actually surprised the question is still open.  If your Employer places restrictions you must ask them allow you.  So really off topic on 2 counts, “corporate IT” issues are off topic, and so is “bypassing restrictions”.

Comment: HTTP relays on the TCP port 80, and HTTPS relays in 443, you can use the HTTPS to create the website, or use proxy to use other ports.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in an Apache server configured as a [forward proxy](https://nitstorm.github.io/blog/apache-forward-reverse-proxies-1/)!

You would set it as your proxy in your browser and connect to it on port 80, and would be able to access your school websites.

Please be advised that rather than listening to some guy on Super-User, you should probably consult your IT department first.

Comment: Also, setting up an open proxy (without authentication) is a terrible idea. Scanners will pick it up pretty quickly and add it to proxy lists, where it will be ab(used) by others. (Those lists are often used by spammers and other questionably legal activity.)

Comment: It may be worth noting that some companies do not permit the use of forward proxies.  Check your acceptable use / security policies before trying this.

Comment: @Baldrickk Absolutely correct. Exactly why I stated that maybe rather than listening to me they should talk to their IT dept. and Bob, you are correct, it is much better to add Basic authentication and SSL/TLS to increase security.

Comment: Thanks a lot, im pretty amazed  about the quick answer and the quality of all the information provided. Yes i think the approach from var @var firstName its pretty useful but what i reallly would like to do its the next: On my restricted machine go to my VPS address on port 80, an then get my school site wich is serving on port 8097. Its that posible using a apache proxy?

Comment: @user2692024 Yes. You set it as your browser proxy, and then you just make a request to your school site!